# All new objects white in 3d View

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I am constructing a view of some rooms of my flat with Blender 2.79 using the default Blender Render. I am not using any textures so far. Since some time, all new objects in this Blender file render as white in the 3d Viewport when using texture viewport shading (`Alt Z`). The image shows how a new cylinder is displayed (after adding it with Shift A):

[image]

This effect does not happen for new Blender documents, just for this file. I have checked all settings, and I don't know what can be the cause. As the Blender document format is binary only, there is no way to peek into it and see what might be the cause.

Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Comment: How are your objects textured? What materials do they have? What render engine are you using? Under what Blender version? How did you setup your scene? Please edit your question and provide all relevant details, as it stands it is impossible to answer your question

Comment: are you using GLSL? do you have any lights?

Comment: Default light, shading is at multitexture, not GLSL.